# input type color in html5 to have random value

Tags: javascript, html

can i make my color value random? 
i have a for loop that creates input fields color,and i want that i have random values of color when they are created.
can i do this with input type=color in html5? or not?
what i tried

```
for(var i=0;i<val;i++)
    {
       randomColor=‘#’+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16); 
       generate(e, i, randomColor);  
    }

function generate(e, i,randomColor)
    {   

    e.innerHTML += "<input type='color' name ='color1' value="randomColor" id='color"+i+"'/>";

}
```

Comment: the problem was in '#' i just put it like this "#" and it worked..sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are building your string wrong, it should be like how you do the id.

```
e.innerHTML += "<input type='color' name ='color1' value='" + randomColor + "' id='color"+i+"'/>";
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and you have "fancy quotes"

```
randomColor=‘#’
            ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
   randomColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
   generate(e, i, randomColor);  
}

function generate(e, i, randomColor) {   
   e.innerHTML += "<input type='color' name ='color1' value='" + randomColor + "' id='color"+i+"'/>";    
}
```